# caption multiple plots in a single chunk in r markdown

Tags: plot, r-markdown, figure, caption

I need a single code chunk in r markdown (pdf output) to generate multiple plots and caption them, but nothing seems to be working. I tried the suggested
fig.cap=c("caption1","caption2")
but nothing happened, there's no caption at all.
How do I manage that?
Here's the code. (For some reason it's not showing the tics, they're there)

````
---
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[croatian]{babel}
  - \pagenumbering{gobble} 
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: pdflatex 
    number_sections: true
    fig_caption: yes 
fontsize: 12pt
---

```{r, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```  

```{r slika2,fig.height=3.5,fig.cap=c("kutijasti dijagram varijable age", "kutijasti dijagram dobi osoba sa srčanom bolesti")}
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
boxplot(age,col="pink")
boxplot(age[target=="1"],col="pink")
```
````

[image]

Comment: `fig.cap=c("caption1","caption2")` should work for _two distinct_ plots. Can you give us the code chunk where this is not working?

Comment: ---
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[croatian]{babel}
  - \pagenumbering{gobble} 
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: pdflatex 
    number_sections: true
    fig_caption: yes 
fontsize: 12pt
---

```{r, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```
```{r slika2,fig.height=3.5,fig.cap=c("kutijasti dijagram varijable age"," kutijasti dijagram dobi osoba sa srčanom bolesti")}
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
boxplot(age,col="pink")
boxplot(age[target=="1"],col="pink")
```

Comment: The chunk `slika2` is generating a single plot instead of two, because of the plot setting `par(mfrow=c(1,2))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you wanted to add the captions for subfigures. If so, specify `fig.subcap` in the R chunk and `\usepackage{subfig}` in `header-includes`.

As @shafee has already pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73696379/caption-multiple-plots-in-a-single-chunk-in-r-markdown#comment130172786_73696379), `par(mfrow=c(1,2))` in the chunk `slika2` merges two `boxplot()` into a single plot instead of two distinct figures. You may need to avoid using `par(mfrow=c(1,2))`.

````
---
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[croatian]{babel}
  - \pagenumbering{gobble}
  - \usepackage{subfig} ## <- Add this
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: pdflatex 
    number_sections: true
    fig_caption: yes 
fontsize: 12pt
---

```{r, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```  

```{r slika2, fig.height = 3.5, fig.cap = "My figures", fig.subcap = c("kutijasti dijagram varijable age", "kutijasti dijagram dobi osoba sa srčanom bolesti"), out.width="50%"}
#par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
boxplot(mtcars, col = "pink")
boxplot(mtcars[mtcars$cyl == "6",], col = "pink")
```
````

[image]